# Does Windows 8 have the bluetooth phone backup and sync features like Windows 7?

Tags: windows-8, sync, bluetooth

I have an old phone and I need to:

- Backup and sync my phone contacts and calendar info.
- Use laptop speakers as a headset.

I was able to perform both of these tasks in Windows 7, but I'm not able to find similar functionality in Windows 8. Any suggestions?

Comment: Once you have added the device, it should work. Do you have all drivers installed?

Comment: Yeah I can transfer files between them. But how to I do what I mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

You mention that your phone is old, in which case you are unlikely to find apps specifically for your phone that manage synchronization for you (I'm assuming you do not have a smartphone).

I would recommend a third-party tool for this (such as [BitPim](http://www.bitpim.org/) for CDMA phones):

[image]

BitPim (pictured above) provides tools for backing up and restoring the filesystem on your phone as well as synchronizing contacts, calendar items, etc.